# Why does Haskell's "flip id" has this type?

Tags: haskell

I'm curious about the expression `flip id` (It's not homework: I found it in the `getOpt` documentation).

I wonder why it has this type:

```
Prelude> :t (flip id)
(flip id) :: b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

For example, `(flip id) 5 (+6)` gives `11`.

I know why `id (+6) 5` gives 11, but I don't "get" the `flip id` thing.

I tried to figure this out myself using pen and paper but couldn't. Could anybody please explain this to me? I mean, how does `flip id` come to have the type `b -> (b -> c) -> c` ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `id` function has this type:

```
id :: a -> a
```

You get an instance of this type, when you replace `a` by `a -> b`:

```
id :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
```

which, because of currying, is the same as:

```
id :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Now apply `flip` to this and you get:

```
flip id :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

In the case of `id (+)` the instance is:

```
id :: (Num a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

Now `flip id` gives you:

```
flip id :: (Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a
```

Side note:  This also shows you how `($)` is the same as `id`, just with a more restricted type:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) f x = f x
-- unpoint:
($) f   = f
-- hence:
($)     = id
```

Comment: Hey, ertes, you seem to have [another account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1488832/ertes), both of which are unregistered. If you register your account, you can [merge them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) and then have a single account for all your answers (which are really good, by the way!).

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Your mention of `$` makes it more intuitive to understand and I'm glad you didn't left it out. It will take my brain a few more days to fully understand your answer.

Comment: Nice answer.  Thinking of `flip id` as `flip ($)` helps a lot.