# GetOpt usage and foldl, flip, id

Tags: haskell

In the second example given in the documentation for System.Console.GetOpt, reproduced here, I am unable to understand or unpack this line:

```
(o,n,[]  ) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)
```

What is this foldl doing, and how does it achieve it? What is the purpose of (flip id)? What is going on?

Code:

```
import System.Console.GetOpt
   import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

   data Options = Options
    { optVerbose     :: Bool
    , optShowVersion :: Bool
    , optOutput      :: Maybe FilePath
    , optInput       :: Maybe FilePath
    , optLibDirs     :: [FilePath]
    } deriving Show

   defaultOptions    = Options
    { optVerbose     = False
    , optShowVersion = False
    , optOutput      = Nothing
    , optInput       = Nothing
    , optLibDirs     = []
    }

   options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Options)]
   options =
    [ Option ['v']     ["verbose"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optVerbose = True }))
        "chatty output on stderr"
    , Option ['V','?'] ["version"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optShowVersion = True }))
        "show version number"
    , Option ['o']     ["output"]
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optOutput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "output")
                "FILE")
        "output FILE"
    , Option ['c']     []
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optInput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "input")
                "FILE")
        "input FILE"
    , Option ['L']     ["libdir"]
        (ReqArg (\ d opts -> opts { optLibDirs = optLibDirs opts ++ [d] }) "DIR")
        "library directory"
    ]

   compilerOpts :: [String] -> IO (Options, [String])
   compilerOpts argv =
      case getOpt Permute options argv of
         (o,n,[]  ) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)
         (_,_,errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ usageInfo header options))
     where header = "Usage: ic [OPTION...] files..."
```

Comment: Try typing `:t flip id` on GHCi. Also this is equivalent to `(,) (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o) n`.

Comment: Yes, but how is the variable o being applied to the defaultOptions variable, and what is the actual function being used by foldl?

Comment: I would probably write `flip id` as `flip ($)` since the latter makes the intent more evident.

Comment: @soon: OK, I've added it as an answer. BTW I love this concept of a *native programming language*, and I should remember to use this term in the future:)

Answer (score 4):

The type of `flip id` is `b -> (b -> c) -> c` and you could find explanations here: [Why does Haskell's "flip id" has this type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339822/why-does-haskells-flip-id-has-this-type)

The `foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o` sub-expression does the following:

1. Takes `defaultOptions` as initial value (`defaultOptions` has type `Options`)
2. Takes each element from `o` (each element has type `Options -> Options`)
3. Folds all elements using `flip id` function (it has `b -> (b -> c) -> c` type)

Since all of `o` elements changes corresponding option in the given configuration, the result of the `foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o` will be a configuration of all parsed options. All missed options replaced with their default values from `defaultOptions`.

The other parts of `(o,n,[]  ) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)` expressions are pretty simple:

1. `(o,n,[]  ) ->` matches a list of parsed options, a list of non-options and an empty list of errors
2. `return (..., n)` just puts the value `(..., n)` into monad `IO (Options, [String])`

Comment: So why the need to reverse o and defaultOptions?

Comment: We do not need to reverse `o` and `defaultOptions`. `foldl` accepts a function of type `a -> b -> a` as first argument, `a` as second, `[b]` as third and produces `a`. Passing `defaultOptions` as second argument we define `a` as `Options`. Passing `o` as third argument, defines `[b]` as `[Options -> Options`]. That is why we need a function of signature `Options -> (Options -> Options) -> Options`. You could just write a lambda `\x f -> f x`, but this approach is ugly, because this function could be easily combined from built-in functions

Answer (score 2):

*(This is not strictly an answer to your question, but @soon asked me to post it anyway.)*

The semantics of each command-line argument you define is described by
a transition function `Options -> Options`. Since you can pass many
arguments to a program, you end up with a list of such transition
functions `[Options -> Options]`. The goal is to compute the sum
effect of these transitions, i.e. an `Options -> Options` that applies
each transition in turn.

A particularly nice way of achieving this is to observe the structure
of endomorphisms `a -> a` for any type `a`:

- `id :: a -> a` is the identity transition function that doesn't actually do anything
- Given two transition functions `f1, f2 :: a -> a`, their composition
  `f1 . f2` corresponds precisely to applying both, in order. Note
  also that this combination is associative, since doing `f2 . f3` and
  then `f1` is the same as doing `f3` followed by `f1 . f2`.

So we have a monoid!

The Haskell standard library `base` already contains this monoid with
the name [`Endo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo).

Using this, we can rewrite

```
foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o
```

in a much nicer way that, in my opinion, makes it immediately obvious what's happening here:

```
appEndo (fold o) defaultOptions
```

by changing the result type of `options` to `[OptDescr (Endo Options)]`; or, if you'd rather not, you can just add the extra `Endo`
line noise at combination time (by writing `appEndo (foldMap Endo o) defaultOptions`). Here, `fold o :: Endo Options` is the composite of all the individual transition functions, and `appEndo (fold o) :: Options -> Options` is how this resulting transition function is finally applied to the initial `Options`.

Note that this also works regardless of the data structure used for `o`: it will work for a list of transition functions, or a tree, or a `Maybe`, because of the associative property of the monoid at hand; and [`fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) is polymorphic enough to expose this.